# Facing issue -oclazyload?

Tags: angularjs, oclazyload

In html:

```
<script
    src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/oclazyload/1.1.0/modules/ocLazyLoad.core.js"></script>
```

In config.js:

```
.state('contact', {
        url : '/contact',
        templateUrl : './contact.html',
        resolve : {
            loadPlugin : function($ocLazyLoad) {
                return $ocLazyLoad
                .load(["./contact.js"
                       ])}}

    });
```

Module:

```
var IPApp=angular.module('IPApp',['ngResource','ui.router','ui.bootstrap','angular-loading-bar','oc.lazyLoad']);
```

Am I missing out something ,anywhere? 
Facing issue while tring to load the controller via oclazyload?

Issue:
[image]

Help me to solve this problem.. 
Thanks.

Comment: did you add oclazyload script after ui-router and before config.js

Comment: @ArefZamani Yes. On landing page, I'm using all the scripts. It was in that order which you have mentioned.

Comment: download https://github.com/ocombe/ocLazyLoad/archive/master.zip and go to dist and add oclazyload.js instead cdn file

Comment: @ArefZamani It's working. Thanks.

Comment: Marked @ArefZamani.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

download [oclazyload from github](http://github.com/ocombe/ocLazyLoad/archive/master.zip) and go to dist and add oclazyload.js instead cdn file